# Where to get ADK and CSR documentation

Tags: csr-adk

I just purchased the CSR8675 Development Kit (DK-CSR8675-10197-2A) from Digi-Key. For the life of me, I can't figure out where to get the full documentation of the development kit, software application documentation, and the ADK3.5.1 software that I need to run with this. Can someone give me specific instructions where I can download the ADK and all necessary documentation to run applications on the dev board?

Comment: Did you ever find out where to get the tools?

Answer (score 1):

Qualcomm acquired CSR, so now you have to create an account at CreatePoint on Qualcomm’s website to access ADKs of their development boards.

Comment: Thanks for the information, and welcome to the site!  It would be really awesome if you could share some references for this as well.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Go to https://myaccount.qualcomm.com/static/registration/login.html?TYPE=33554433&REALMOID=06-00080ed5-4a1b-1529-9b91-2e0d0a35f024&GUID=0&SMAUTHREASON=0&METHOD=GET&SMAGENTNAME=-SM-3fDqOYKHJxzpIZPr%2fn8KIx3w0nVTe5%2bfAFza9cSe402EShObc8Lno0LoyzNHQPLP&TARGET=-SM-HTTPS%3a%2f%2fcreatepoint%2eqti%2equalcomm%2ecom%2fdashboard

Register an account, use to pull down to select chipset, under tools/software tab one should find the ADK downloads.